# EF (6) Code First desired model

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm having difficulty trying to represent my desired data model with a code first approach. A user can have 1-N Entries, an Entry has 1-N comments -all of which works correctly.

My issue arises when attempting to go deeper with the vote class. What I'm trying to achieve is to allow a single Vote for each comment for each user. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Entry
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Vote vote { get; set; }

}

public class Vote
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: one solution is to use a composite key for table vote, the key being CommentId + UserId.

Comment: @tschmit007 - I did attempt a composite key, but this resulted in a vote_id and user_id key being placed in the comment table. This appears backwards to me, I wish only a single comment record with many vote records per user, or in other words it would seem to me that the keys should be stored in the votes table, not the comment table?

Comment: you need an `ICollection<Vote> Votes` property in your Comment class

Comment: Many thanks, I think I had it this way first but ran across other unrelated issues -it appears to be correct now.